# Shiny UI conditionalPanel passing input selections back and forth

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny webpage with a UI that is conditional to choosing "Alfa/Beta" at the top of the sidebarPanel, and then choosing from a list of fields in each case.

I managed to get to the point of having a `ui.R` that was working if I hard-coded the lists of values of the selectInputs in the `ui.R` file, but now I want to have a working version that combines the selectInputs in `ui.R` with the content coming from fetching the data from a db in `server.R`.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass the list of possible values from the db selects in `server.R` to the selectInputs in `ui.R` and then pass the selections back to `server.R` to produce the plots. The examples I have read in the tutorial don't have this high-level of conditionalPanels, which is what is confusing me.

I sketched out how I imagine this would work, but left some SOMEHOWs where I am not sure how to do it (see below).

Any ideas how to pass these selections back and forth?

## ui.R

```
## Old hard-coded values
# alfaFieldA = c("One","Ttwo")
# ...

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Page Dev"),
  sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("option","Alfa/Beta",c("Alfa","Beta")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Alfa'",
                       selectInput("SOMEHOW.alfaFieldA","Alfa FieldA",choices=alfaFieldA,selected=alfaFieldA,multiple=T)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Beta'",
                       selectInput("SOMEHOW.betaFieldA" ,"Beta FieldA" ,choices=betaFieldA,selected=betaFieldA,multiple=T)
      ),
      wellPanel(
      p(strong("Selection from lists from either Alfa or Beta:")),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Alfa'",
                       selectInput("SOMEHOW.alfaFieldB","Alfa FieldB",choices=alfaFieldB,selected=alfaFieldB,multiple=T)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Alfa'",
                       selectInput("SOMEHOW.alfaFieldC","Alfa FieldC",choices=alfaFieldC,selected=alfaFieldC,multiple=T)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Beta'",
                       selectInput("SOMEHOW.betaFieldB" ,"Beta FieldB" ,choices=betaFieldB,selected=betaFieldB,multiple=T)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Beta'",
                       selectInput("SOMEHOW.betaFieldC" ,"Beta FieldC" ,choices=betaFieldC,selected=betaFieldC,multiple=T)
      )
    )
   ),

  # display the tabset depending on choosing Alfa or Beta above.
  mainPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Alfa'",
                     tabsetPanel(tabPanel("A1"),tabPanel("A2"))),
    conditionalPanel(condition="input.option=='Beta'",
                     tabsetPanel(tabPanel("B1"),tabPanel("B2"),tabPanel("B3")))
  )
))
```

## server.R

```
library(RMySQL)
shinyServer(function(input, output, clientData) {

  # Gather data
  dbcon = dbConnect(MySQL(),user="userRO",password="xxxxx",host="my-host-01",port=5000,dbname="mydb")
  fa      = dbSendQuery(dbcon, "select a, b, c from mytableA")
  fa_data = fetch(fa, n=-1)

  fa_data = fa_data[nchar(fa_data$a)!=0,]
  # make 'mytableA.a' list visible to conditionalPanel selectInput alfaFieldA

  fb      = dbSendQuery(dbcon, "select a, b, c from mytableB")
  fb_data = fetch(fb, n=-1)
  fb_data = fb_data[nchar(fb_data$a)!=0,]
  dbret   = dbDisconnect(dbcon)
  # make 'mytableB.a' list visible to conditionalPanel selectInput betaFieldA SOMEHOW

  output$A1 <- renderGvis({
  # manipulate fa_data for selected FieldA and FieldB values SOMEHOW and plot something
  })
  output$B1 <- renderGvis({
  # manipulate fb_data for selected FieldA, FieldB and FieldC values SOMEHOW and plot something
  })
  # ...
})
```

Comment: I guess you need to use `observe()` in Server.R. I have my own issues with this, but you can check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809824/shiny-use-results-of-function-call-in-observe-in-output) where `observe()` is used in working example.

Comment: I don't understand RMySQL, but could'nt you use `updateSelectInput()` ?